# Como Proteger contraseña en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estoy con un controlador para crear usuarios, pero no sé como encriptar la contraseña!

si me pueden ayudar, por favor

Funcion Store:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:10',
        ]);
        $show = User::create($validatedData);

        return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'Usuario Agregado');
    }
```

Comment: A lo que voy es que no sé como implementarlo

Answer (score 3):

Para encriptar una contraseña se usa `Hash::make`

```php
Hash::make($request->password)
```

Quedaría así implementado (este método es de laravel breeze).

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

[fuente](https://github.com/laravel/breeze/blob/1.x/stubs/default/App/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisteredUserController.php#L34)